# Not able to access Subfolders | Php framework

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I am editing a site that is made using some framework on PHP doesn't show which.
All the public files like CSS,JS are inside a Public directory. I want to upload a separate site within the domain like www.domain.com/newsite i have created the folder new site but i am not able to access it it goes to 404 page not found.

the Htacess of the root is as below

```
RewriteEngine on



RewriteRule ^(?!sitemap\.xml$).(.*)\.xml$ [R=404,L]
RewriteRule ^(?!robots\.txt$).(.*)\.txt$ [R=404,L]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteRule    ^$    public/    [L]
RewriteRule    (.*) public/$1    [L]

<ifModule mod_headers.c>
    Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
</ifModule>
```

I created anther folder inside public directory newsite still now able to open it.

Htacess inside public directory is

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l



RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?url=$1 [QSA,L]
```

Any suggestions how can i access the folder directly

Comment: would it work with `RewriteRule ^newsite/ - [L]` at the top of root htaccess?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You only need to tell the root htaccess not to rewrite to `public` directory when your new folder is involved in the request. Currently, you have this part of code

```
RewriteRule    ^$    public/    [L]
RewriteRule    (.*) public/$1    [L]
```

which means: rewrite root page `/` to `public` folder (first rule) and rewrite **everything** to `public` folder as well (second rule). Note by the way that your first rule is then useless.

Anyway, you need to add a condition to reach your goal

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/newsite
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ public/$1 [L]
```

which means: rewrite everything **except** `newsite` folder to `public` folder.

At the end, your root htaccess should look like this

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^(?!sitemap\.xml$).(.*)\.xml$ [R=404,L]
RewriteRule ^(?!robots\.txt$).(.*)\.txt$ [R=404,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/newsite
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ public/$1 [L]

<ifModule mod_headers.c>
    Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
</ifModule>
```

Note the presence of `RewriteBase` which is always a good habit, especially when dealing with virtual directories created by some rules. Note also that your two xml rules could be rewritten in a more clever/cleaner way

Answer (score 0):

Try to add

```
RewriteBase /newsite/
```

Write this line under "RewriteEngine On"

Answer (score 0):

Try to use below rules,

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteRule ^(?!sitemap\.xml$).(.*)\.xml$ [R=404,L]
RewriteRule ^(?!robots\.txt$).(.*)\.txt$ [R=404,L]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]

#Adding exception for newsite if not new site do rewrite to public/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^!newsite

RewriteRule ^$ public/    [L]
RewriteRule (.*) public/$1    [L]
```

You are getting not found error because you are currently internally rewriting everything to public directory please try the new rules if you haven't.